# GRAILS: method for permalink/slug generation?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, internationalization

Does anybody have a quick method to generate slugs and permalinks in Grails 1.3.7/2.0.0.RC1?
The main restriction: this method should work with non-latin characters.

Russian/bulgarian cirillic, deutsch umlauts etc...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

### Grails 2.0.0.RC1

From the [2.0.0.RC1 docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew):

> Link Generation API
>
> A general purpose LinkGenerator class is now available that is usable
> anywhere within a Grails application and not just within the context
> of a controller. For example if you need to generate links in a
> service or an asynchronous background job outside the scope of a
> request:

```
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

def generateLink() { grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller:"book", action:"list") }
```

Although it's not stated explicitly, I assume the reference to `grailsLinkGenerator` is obtained via dependency injection

### Grails 1.3.7

You can use either the [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) or [resource](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) tags to generate links. If you're generating permalinks, I assume you'll want these to be absolute URLs. If so, you'll need to use either the `absolute` or `base` attribute when using these tags.

If you use the `absolute` attribute, be sure to set the value of `grails.serverURL` in `Config.groovy`

### Link Permanence

The text above describes how to generate links to resources in a Grails application, but doesn't say anything about how to make these links permanent. AFAIK, the link to a resource will always remain the same as long as you don't change anything that is used in the URL mapping scheme (as defined in `UrlMappings.groovy`)

By default the URL mapping scheme uses

- the resource's ID
- the controller name
- the action name

So if you never change these for the links of interest, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks )) But my question regarding the SEO FRIENDLY PERMALINK GENERATION from non latin languages like russian... )) Example: http://mysite.com/blog/Вася/Пупкин/Должен_Быть-Латинницей... should be http://mysite.com/blog/vasya/pupkin/dolzhen-byt-latinnitsej

Answer (score 0):

As easy as:

```
title.replaceAll("[\\W]+", "-")
```

That makes it.

Comment: A better aproximation to a full SLUG generation: ``title.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\W]+", "-")``